# Excel filter and regex match numbers to another worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I'm a bit of an Excel noob so bear with me here. I have the following abridged sheet:

```
Sheet1
         H                        AP               AO
1 Transaction Description    Employee Name        Type
2 ER 12345678                    blank             blank
3 ER 13182984                    blank             blank
4 ER 18213289                    blank             blank
5 ER 13829429                    blank             blank
6 ER 89234024                    blank             blank
```

And another sheet in the same file to reference the names against:

```
Sheet2
       E                           I
1 Expense Report Number      Employee Name     
2 12345678                    Chris Rock         
3 13182984                    Hank Hill          
4 18213289                    Tom Sawyer         
5 13829429                    Elon Musk          
6 89234024                    Tupac Shakur
```

And I was wondering how to efficiently fill in the first excel sheet's Employee Name and Type columns from the matching report number of the second sheet as such:

```
Sheet1
        H                            AP              AO
1 Transaction Description      Employee Name        Type   
2 ER 12345678                    Chris Rock           A
3 ER 13182984                    Hank Hill            A
4 ER 18213289                    Tom Sawyer           A
5 ER 13829429                    Elon Musk            A
6 ER 89234024                    Tupac Shakur         A
```

My attempt so far:

```
Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
RE.pattern = "(\d{8})"
Set allMatches = RE.Execute(ActiveSheet.Region ("H:H") #extract the 8 numbers
#somehow extract the 8 numbers to reference against the second sheet
With .Columns(AP)
      .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Formula = "=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(reference number,EEM BI + mapping!I:I,2,0)),""Check employee ID"",VLOOKUP(reference number,EEM BI + mapping!I:I,2,0))"
```

As you can see I'm pretty lost in this code.. Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Why VBA and Regex?  Why not just simple formula to split out the numbers, and VLOOKUP worksheet function?

Comment: what are the columns names in Sheet2?

Comment: can you split sheet1.columnH into two?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I apologize, I come from a programming background, and regex is what was most familiar to me.

Comment: @jsotola The column names are still the letters, unless you're referring to the headers, then those are indicated by index 1 but no I can't split the column into two unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

In your table in Sheet1 if the 8 digit number always starts at position 4, as you show, you can use the `MID` function seen in the formula below.  If not, we would merely have to change `MID` to something a bit more complex, depending on the real data.  No need for REGEX unless the text analysis is complex.

Given the order of `Employee Name` and `Expense Report Number` in your lookup table, `INDEX(MATCH(...` would be one solution.

Although you could use `LOOKUP`, it may be more efficient to use `INDEX(MATCH...`.  `LOOKUP`, among other things, to work properly, requires that your lookup table be sorted.  That is not necessary with `INDEX/MATCH`.

Something like

```
=INDEX(EmployeeName,MATCH(--MID(H2,4,8),ExpenseReportNumber,0))
```

*For efficiency, the references to the two columns (`EmployeeName` and `ExpenseReportNumber`) should be as short as possible.  Whole column references (eg: `$E:$E` and `$I:$I` will work, but will take longer to execute.*

Comment: Thanks for the response! I forgot to include that my second sheet is an abridged version as well. I tried the following in order to reference the two columns: =VLOOKUP(--MID(H2,4,8),Employee_Exp_Rpt_Nbr_Tbl!E:I,E:I,FALSE) where column E is the name and I is the 8 digit number that sheet1 is supposed to match, but this isn't quite working. Any tips?

Comment: You should **always** post **realistic** examples.  Help for `VLOOKUP` will tell you that `lookup_value` must be in the first column of the table, and that `col_index_num` must be a number (or an expression that resolves to a number).  It would seem that neither your table, nor your adaptation of the formula, meets those criteria.  You can use a combination of `Match` to obtain the correct row number from column I, and `Index` to return the item from the array in column E.  You can use the same `MID` formula to return the 8 digit number.

Answer (score 1):

try this test code

```
Sub Test()

    Dim ddd As Variant                                ' convert sheet1.columnH into an array
    ddd = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("h2:h6").Value       ' 2D array 1 x N
    ddd = Application.Transpose(ddd)                  ' 2D array N x 1
    ddd = Application.Transpose(ddd)                  ' this changes to 1D array

    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To UBound(ddd)                          ' remove the "ER" from each member of the array
      ddd(i) = Split(ddd(i))(1)
    Next i

    Dim findMe As String
    Dim rng As Range

    For Each rng In Sheets("Sheet2").Range("e2:e6")

        findMe = rng.Value

        For i = 1 To UBound(ddd)
            If StrComp(findMe, ddd(i), vbTextCompare) = 0 Then                                                                      
                Sheets("Sheet1").Range("ap1").Offset(i) = rng.Offset(0, 4).Value
                Sheets("Sheet1").Range("ao1").Offset(i) = "A"
            End If
        Next i
    Next rng
End Sub
```